# How to edit value in the TextInput React native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Setting value to the textinput from state and updating the state onChangeText. Still the value in the textInput is not changing. There is no problem while running it in the simulator. It occurs only when running in the device. Same code no problem with android device and emulator.

```
class CompanyDetailsInput extends Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    this.state = {
        email: props.profile.Email,
    }

render() {
    return (


                    <TextInput
                        value={this.state.email}
                        editable={this.props.editable}
                        onChangeText={(email) => {
                            this.email(email)
                        }}

                        autoCorrect={false}
                        blurOnSubmit={false}
                        returnKeyType={"next"}
                        keyboardType={"default"}
                    </TextInput>
)}
}
```

Comment: Please provide code for understanding and exact solution.

Answer (score 1):

you'll need to `setState` your `onChangeText`, so;

```
class CompanyDetailsInput extends Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    this.state = {
        email: props.profile.Email,
    }

render() {
    return (
        <TextInput
          value={this.state.email}
          editable={this.props.editable}
          onChangeText={(x)=> this.setState({ email: x })}
          autoCorrect={false}
          blurOnSubmit={false}
          returnKeyType="next"
          keyboardType="default"
        />
       )
      }
     }
```